# Scripting in unity3d

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine

Hey guys I don't understand the concept of scripting in unity3d. Let's say I want to click a button and make an object move, where do I place the script in button or??? And how do I call the object to move

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials

These are ultra-basic quetions which suggest you haven't read the docs yet. The page linked above has video tutorials if you don't like reading.

Watch a few, download Unity, try them out, and when you have a clearer idea of what you do/don't understand, come back and ask specific questions